# Bootstrap navbar toggle menu button is not working as expected

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i am unable to get the bootstrap collapse function working in my angular, menu bar collapses into single hamburger icon when i reduce the page size however icon is not clickable, nothing happens. any help to get this working is highly appreciated.

I have installed the following:

npm install bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My angular.json file:

```
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

my app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LeftMenuComponent } from './left-menu/left-menu.component';
import { RightMenuComponent } from './right-menu/right-menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from './gallery/gallery.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus/contactus.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ButtonOverviewExample} from './content/content.component';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
 import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
 import {HomepageComponent} from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LeftMenuComponent,
    RightMenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    GalleryComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactusComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    ProductsComponent
      ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule
      ],
exports: [
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "huss-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.12.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.0",
    "latest-version": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.45.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: So first code example (HTML file) is the working code right? And you want same implementation in Angular as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Click on the menu icon isnt working. Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please share your angular component HTML for this navigation menu?

Comment: I was able to just fix the issue by adding the below two scripts lines in the index.html file of the main project, i was adding these lines in component.html file which wasnt working. 

  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just fix the issue by adding the below two scripts lines in the index.html file of the main project, i was adding these lines in component.html file which wasnt working.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```