# Bootstrap collapsible menu not expanding on click

Tags: html, angular, menu, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to have my navbar collapsed menu expand when clicked when the screen is small. I'm using a navbar from Bootstrap that I've tweaked for my needs (splitting my links to each end of the bar). Right now, the links collapse when the screen gets small, but nothing happens when the accordion button is pressed.

Here are my `dependencies` from the *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
},
```

And here are my scripts and styles from the *angular.json*:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
],
```

Finally here's my HTML:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
    <img src="../../assets/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class="helmet-logo">
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Teams </a>
        

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Seasons
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2023</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2022</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2021</a>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" >
        <div class="navbar-nav" id="Auth-buttons">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

So far I've tried adding these scripts from another related SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864896/bootstrap-navbar-toggle-menu-button-is-not-working-as-expected) to the *index.html* file and running but there was no change. I've attempted to use the developer console to debug but I don't see the Bootstrap script file and putting a breakpoint on a mouse click didn't show me anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`data-bs-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#javascript) for Bootstrap 5 instead of `data-*` which is for the version before Bootstrap 5.

```
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
  aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
>
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

...

<button
    class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
    type="button"
    id="dropdownMenuButton"
    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false"
>
    Seasons
</button>
```

As you import the Bootstrap Bundle (*bootstrap.bundle.min.js*), you can remove the *jquery.json* from the `scripts` array in your *angular.json* file.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d2vs9j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)